# Grabbing unversioned externals into svn check-out

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I hope this question can make sense. I use svn externals generally to grab versioned items from another svn check-in. This is not what I am after. We have many .dlls and many sources files from third party providers we do not want to check in to our svn.

So my question is, is there a way to automagically grab these files when we check out from svn? Preferably for the first time only? Is there a way of attached a script to execute on tortoise to grab unversioned files etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of TortoiseSVN you can write and use client-side hooks (which can perform any operations, unrelated directly to Subversion, repository and Working Copy)

Post-update hook may be good candidate

Comment: thank you this solution works. why they call it post update hook or client side hook I don't know. haha